# If Statement help mutiple and, or statements

Tags: c#

```
if (((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) && (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))) || ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightShift)) && (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))))
        {
            print("Well done! Next Key: " + "A");
        }
```

What's Wrong with this if statement?

Comment: What did you expect this code to do? What do you observe?

Comment: @KlausGütter So if you type uppercase A with either shift button It would say well done

Comment: place a breakpoint. the debugger is your best friend

Comment: Use the power of methods to make your code more readable. For example, compare your code with `if (ArePressed(KeyCode.LeftShift, KeyCode.A) || ArePressed(KeyCode.RightShift, KeyCode.A))` or maybe even `if (IsPressedWithShift(KeyCode.A))`. If you manage to make your code so simple that it is *obviously correct*, you'll drastically reduce the number of bugs.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have too many parentheses on the left side of the OR. Also, your parentheses are not correct on the right side. I believe you want to set it up like this.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) && (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightShift)))
```

Edit: Revised because checking for A twice is redundant as pointed out by @Caius-jard.